# MySQL запрос сортировки по алфавиту сперва буквы, а потом цифры

Tags: sql, select

Задача сортировать данные из таблицы в алфавитном порядке по полю `title`, хранимые данные могут быть русского или английского алфавита и начинаться с цифры.

Вот простенький запрос который я написал

```
SELECT title FROM films ORDER BY `title`
```

Как видите по умолчанию база данных возвращает данные которые начинаются с числа, а мне нужно что бы сперва были данные начинающиеся с букв.

Помогите или подскажите как до ума довести данный запрос.

```
"2001: A Space Odyssey"
"2001: A Space Odyssey"
"2001: A Space Odyssey"
"2001: A Space Odyssey"
"Breaking Bad"
"Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid"
"Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid"
"Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid"
"Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid"
"Casablanca"
"Casablanca"
"Casablanca"
"Casablanca"
"Charade"
"Charade"
"Charade"
"Charade"
"Cool Hand Luke"
"Cool Hand Luke"
"Cool Hand Luke"
"Cool Hand Luke"
"dfg"
"dfgdg"
"dfsgreg"
"Get Shorty "
"Get Shorty "
"Get Shorty "
"Get Shorty "
```

Еще рассматриваю вариант отсортировать этот массив данных средствами php, но хочется узнать можно ли решить данную задачу исключительно используя SQL.

Comment: заменить в order by все цифры на фигурную скобку '{', например. А как это делать, зависит от используемого диалекта sql. скорее всего чем то вроде replace, хотя громоздко выйдет. При условии что ваш sql сортирует в порядке ascii кодов символов и '{' у него идет после букв

Comment: Для MySQL, например, просто `ORDER BY 0+title, title`. Для других СУБД иначе. Указывайте точный диалект.

Comment: Спасибо, все оказалось на много проще чем я думал.